Download large file from s3 using aioboto3 and aiofiles is really slow
I have high-load system, where many users could upload large files (+1gb).
After uploading, sometimes, I need to download them from S3 to calculate some meta information.
Currently I'm using this code to do this (look at fetch_file):
def _get_file_extension(key) -> str
    ...

class S3Storage:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self._config = botocore.config.Config(
            read_timeout=read_timeout,
            connect_timeout=connect_timeout,
            retries={
                "total_max_attempts": ...,
                "max_attempts": ...,
            },
            signature_version="v4",
        )
        self._session = self._create_session()

    def _create_session():
        return aioboto3.Session()

    def _create_client(self):
        return self._session.client(
            service_name="s3",
            endpoint_url=self._endpoint_url,
            region_name=self._region,
            aws_access_key_id=self._access_key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=self._secret_access_key,
            config=self._config,
        )

    async def fetch_file(self, key: str, bucket: str | None = None) -> str:
        try:
            async with self._create_client() as client:
                response = await client.get_object(Bucket=bucket or self._bucket, Key=key)
                async with aiofiles.tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
                    "wb",
                    suffix=_get_file_extension(key),
                    delete=False,
                ) as file:
                    async for chunk in response["Body"]:
                        await file.write(chunk)
                return str(file.name)
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            ...
        except aiohttp.ServerTimeoutError as e:
            ...
        except (
            botocore.exceptions.BotoCoreError,
            aiohttp.ClientError,
        ) as e:
            ...

For some reason, this realisation is really slow. After profiling I've found out that it takes 300 seconds to download 1gb file. All 300 seconds were spent exactly at fetch_file method.
Could someone help me to figure out, why it takes so long to download file from s3 and what I could do with this.

Can you give a bit more information on the infrastructure you are running it on? EC2, ECS or Lambda and also the configs? I would guess that its a memmory problem because the file is large and your are first downloading it into RAM and then write it to disk. When there is limited RAM/Memmory availlable the data is written to swap which can be very slow depending on your configuration. I would try to use the "download_file" method or even download the file in chunks with intermediate writes to disk.

both in the local environment and EC2 slow. Which part of code causing memory problems? NamedTemporaryFile saves everything in local storage and storing in memory only one chunk. client.get_object also saves in memory only specific chunk. Could you provide more details please. Also, config for s3 provided in init

I adapted your code from the 'fetch_file' method. Replace the whole code inside the try block with this one:
async with self._create_client() as client:
    async with aiofiles.tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
        "wb",
        suffix=_get_file_extension(key),
        delete=False,
    ) as file:
        response = await client.download_file(Bucket=bucket or self._bucket, Key=key, Filename=file)
    return str(file.name)

I hope this will work. Currently i have no way of testing this!
